# How to create a ragged edge at top of a div?

Tags: html, css

I have this div for which I want to create a top ragged edge. Looking like say, a torn paper edge. I have a png file.

I tried using a background-image declaration, adjusting its y-position to move it up, but the problem is that as it goes "out of the div", it is not displayed.

I tried z-index to no avail. 
Thanks for any help

the CSS

```
#maininner {
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("/image/wonderlit-tmeplate/paper-ragged-top.png");
  background-position: 1px -9px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

image: 
imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/hufz.jpg

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS as a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: **I tried using a background-image declaration, adjusting its y-position** <- Can we see that?

Comment: @Mr.Alien:  Yes We Can ..? :)

Comment: Here's the css. I wanted to add an image but being new to Stack, I'm forbidden.

Comment: You should really provide the image (and eventually a fiddle). Try uploading it in an external service like imageshack...

Comment: Thanks, here it is: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/hufz.jpg/

Comment: Don't use negative offset for the background image but instead use padding-top to push the content of the div down.

Comment: @Ceres : Good suggestion but didn't work. same result, the image doesn't get displayed outside of the div.